# NSolve gives weird result for $n=101$ with NSolve[$\frac{d}{dx}\prod \limits_{k=1}^n (x-k)$==0,x]

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Coming from this post: [What would be the roots of the derivate of this polynom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294536/what-would-be-the-roots-of-the-derivate-of-this-polynom/) I did a quick check with Mathematica and arrived at a wrong result. I was initially confused but chose to trust Mathematica and think later.

```
f[x_, n_] := Product[(x - k), {k, 1, n}]
NSolve[D[f[x, 100], x] == 0, x]
NSolve[D[f[x, 101], x] == 0, x]
NSolve[D[f[x, 102], x] == 0, x]
```

For $n=100$ I get 99 different results, for $n=102$ I get 101 different results, and for $n=101$ I get 100 times $51.$ as a result.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: using `Reals` as the domain (`NSolve[D[f[x,101], x] == 0, x, Reals]`) gets rid of the issue.

Comment: btw, this issue does not arise in version 9 (windows 10)

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 11.2 on Unix.

Comment: Also no poblems with MMA v11.0.1

Comment: From a comment in the linked question, setting the Precision to 20 also solves the problem. Still, I find this very curious

Comment: With version 12 on my Mac, `Length@NSolve[D[f[x, #], x] == 0, x] & /@ 
  Range[100, 102] === Range[100, 102] - 1` evaluates to `True`

Comment: It is not the best conditioned of problems.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau:  Indeed.  Note that this looks a lot like a derivative of [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial), which is a well-known ill-conditioned problem in numerical analysis.

Comment: Some evidence of ill-condtioning: `Table[x /. 
  FindRoot[D[ff[x, 101], x], {x, k, k + 1}, Method -> "Brent"], {k, 
  100}]`.  More evidence: `D[ff[x, 101], {x, 2}] /. 
   Table[FindRoot[D[ff[x, 101], x], {x, k, k + 1}, Method -> "Brent", 
     WorkingPrecision -> 16], {k, 100}] // Abs // ListLogPlot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, solutions for this problem with n greater than approximately 10 are all wrong (**no matter if they are different or equal to each other**).

While for `n = 7` the max value of `D[f[x, 7], x]` on solutions is approximately $10^{-10}$, the max value of `D[f[x, 13], x]` on solutions reaches approximately 3.9, too far from zero. Moreover, a simple analysis shows that, for any given `n`, there must be `n - 1` roots of `D[f[x, n], x]`, that any root belongs to the interval between `1` and `n`, and that there must be one and only one root in every interval between `m` and `m + 1`, `m = 1, 2, ..., n - 1`.

However, `NSolve[D[f[x, 100], x] == 0, x]` gives us three roots between 4 and 5, ten roots between 5 and 6, and sixteen roots greater than 100, e.g. `x = 282.634` (I believe, numbers can vary depending on version of Mathematica, I use 8.0.4). So, if solutions are wrong, it does not matter whether they are different or equal to each other. Much higher precision computations are required.

Answer (score 4):

The slick way to go about this is to use the logarithmic derivative instead in `NSolve[]`, which has a pretty nice formula:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log\left(\prod_{k=1}^n (x-k)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{x-k}$$

Obviously, this has the same roots as the derivative. (This is not true in general, but here the polynomial and its derivative are relatively prime.)

That is to say,

```
NSolve[Sum[1/(x - k), {k, 1, n}] == 0, x]
```

Here is a plot of the maximum absolute error for the naive and the log derivative approaches, compared with a solution computed at higher precision:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[Table[Block[{sol, r1, r2},
             sol = Sort[x /. NSolve[D[Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}], x] == 0, x, 
                        WorkingPrecision -> 20]];
             r1 = Sort[x /. NSolve[D[Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}], x] == 0, x]];
             r2 = Sort[x /. NSolve[Sum[1/(x - k), {k, 1, n}] == 0, x]];
             {Norm[sol - r1, ∞], Norm[sol - r2, ∞]}], {n, 3, 50}]],
             DataRange -> {3, 50}, PlotLegends -> {"naive", "log derivative"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: On an unrelated note, copying images from Wolfram One is a pain in the bum; I had to make do with taking a screenshot instead.